# Request data Modifiy in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a class with APIView, which accept request. from there, I pass the request to 2 different methods, but when I print data from 2nd function, it is modified by first method.

**Sample**

```
class events(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        self.tinybird(data)
        self.events(data)
```

I was expecting to have same copy of data in both method, but `tinyBird` method changes one line as `del product['options']` and due to this I am not able to get `product['options']` in events() method. As I am passing data separately to both functions, how data modification of 1st function affect data of 2nd function.

**Tried**

I tried to send copy of request to each function or one function but still same issue.

```
data1 = request.copy()
data2 = request.copy()
self.tinybird(data1)
self.events(data2)
```

still data2 throw keyerror on data2['options']

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because even though you are passing copies of request.data to the two methods, they are still referencing the same dictionary,not an actual copy of it. You should use a deep copy before passing it to the two methods like this

```
import copy

class Events(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        self.tinybird(copy.deepcopy(data))
        self.events(copy.deepcopy(data))
```